# Calculate sample proportions for n=1000 and mean of sample proportions in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics, dna-sequence

I want to calculate the mean of the sample proportions of 5-Mers that are AATAA. But stuck in obtaining 100 samples each of length 1000 of sample proportion of 5-MERS that are AATAA from the first 100,000 nucleotides of NC_006620.3

```
library(ape)
library(seqinr)
library("stringr")

dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3") # 

dog_ch38 <- str_to_upper(dog_ch38)

    enter code here

get_DNA_sample <- function(DNA, n){
       N <- str_length(DNA)
       start <- sample(1:(N - n + 1), size = 1)
       return(str_sub(DNA, start, start + n - 1))
   }
get_DNA_sample(dog_ch38, 1000)
```

Comment: What is your actual question? You're just making statements now. Also, from the site help section: _"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem."_ (the last needs sample data or such)

Comment: I want to calculate the mean value of the sample proportion of 5-mers that are AATAA from the 100 samples each of length 1000.
Dataset: dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3", as.character = TRUE)

Comment: Here is my code:
# This asks it to return a list of character vectors. 
dog_ch38 <- read.GenBank("NC_006620.3", as.character = TRUE)
#get first 100000 records
dog_ch38 <- dog_ch38$NC_006620.3[1:100000]
#get 1000 lenght random stirng function
get_DNA_sample <- function(DNA, n){
  N <- str_length(DNA)
  start <- sample(1:(N - n + 1), size = 1)
  return(str_sub(DNA, start, start + n - 1))
}
 #k-mars of AATAA 100 times
for(i in 1:100)
{  txt<-get_DNA_sample(txt,1000) 
  txt
  s <- DNAString(txt)
  km <- oligonucleotideFrequency(s[1:1000], 5)
  km["AATAA"]
 
}km["AATAA"]/100

Comment: **DON'T put information in the comments.** Put it in the question body. Please read the help section of Stack Overflow on how to ask a good question.